# Change DateTime to just Date in Android

Tags: android

I am getting a Datetime like "**2017-06-29T08:53:06.511100Z**" from API that
needs to converted to just date "**2017-06-29**"

I keep getting errors with SimpleDateFormat

Comment: what you tried so far ???

Comment: use `.substring(0,10)`

Comment: You can split that string using "T" and store it in array and then take first position of that array.

Comment: may be you should check first for the valid format for "2017-06-29T08:53:06.511100Z"  this string to get the time or you can say to iniatialize date than you can change the date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your format is wrong, You can use following method to get the date

```
String dateValue = getDateFromatedString("2017-06-29T08:53:06.511100Z");
```

Method:

```
public static String getDateFromatedString(String inputDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (date == null) {
        return "";
    }

    SimpleDateFormat convetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    return convetDateFormat.format(date);
}
```